Synchronize value of useField from vee-validate with v-model of vue 3.4?
I am trying to create a reusable Textarea component, using vee-validate 4.13.1 and
vue 3.4.21 and storybook Below the code of Textarea.vue
<template>
  <FormControl :valid="isValid">
    <label v-if="label" class="lib__form__label">{{ label }}</label>    
    <span v-if="description" class="lib__form__desc">{{ description }}</span>
    <textarea
      v-model="value"
      :disabled
      :name
      :placeholder
      :readonly="readOnly"
      :required
      class="lib__form__textarea"
      rows="5"
    >
    </textarea>
    <ErrorMessage v-if="!isValid" :id="errorMessagesId" :errors="errors" />
  </FormControl>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import ErrorMessage from '@/components/display/ErrorMessage.vue'
import FormControl from '@/components/layout/FormControl.vue'
import { initTextarea } from '@assets/framework/js/textarea'
import { computed, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useField } from 'vee-validate'

interface Props {
  /** Permet d'indiquer si la textarea est requise ou non. */
  required?: boolean
  /** Permet d'indiquer si la textarea est désactivée (disabled) ou non. */
  disabled?: boolean
  /** Permet d'indiquer si la textaera est en mode lecture seule (readOnly) ou non. */
  readOnly?: boolean
  /** Propriété qui définit le label associé à la Textarea. */
  label?: string | null
  /** Propriété de type String qui permet d'ajouter une description sous le label. */
  description?: string
  /** Propriété qui définit la longueur maximale du texte que l'utilisateur peut saisir. */
  placeholder?: string
  /** Propriété qui définit le nom de la textarea. */
  name: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  label: null,
  placeholder: '',
  disabled: false,
  required: false,
  readOnly: false,
})

defineModel<string | null>({ required: true })

const { errors, value, meta } = useField<string | null>(props.name)

//Vérifier la validité de l'input après la saisie (renvoyer undefined au chargement du composant: utile pour le syle CSS)
const isValid = computed<boolean | undefined>(() =>
  meta.dirty === false ? undefined : errors.value.length === 0
)

//IDs des messages d'erreurs relatives à l'input
const errorMessagesId = computed<string>(() => `error-messages-${props.name}`)

//Appel au script JS initTextArea
onMounted(() => initTextarea())
</script>


and here is the Story from Teaxtarea.stories.ts
export const DisabledReadOnly: Story = {
  name: 'Disabled / ReadOnly',
  render: () => ({
    components: { Textarea },
    setup() {
      const disabledModelValue = ref('Cette zone de texte est désactivée')
      const readonlyModelValue = ref('Cette zone de texte est en lecture seule')

      console.log('Disabled Model Value:', disabledModelValue.value)
      console.log('ReadOnly Model Value:', readonlyModelValue.value)
      return { disabledModelValue, readonlyModelValue }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
      <!-- Disabled Textarea -->
      <Textarea
        v-model="disabledModelValue"
        label="Disabled Textarea" 
        name="textareaDisabled"
        :disabled="true" 
      />
      
      <!-- ReadOnly Textarea -->
      <Textarea
        v-model="readonlyModelValue" 
        label="ReadOnly Textarea" 
        name="textareaReadonly"
        :readOnly="true"
      />
    </div>
    `
  })
}


the disabledModelValue and readonlyModelValue are logged correctly but not displayed in the two textarea, I think i am using defineModel() in a wrong way. Or i should synchronize value and defineModel()
defineModel<string | null>({ required: true })

const { errors, value, meta } = useField<string | null>(props.name)

How can I correct my component?

Yes, looks like you need to link the value from useField() with the components v-model binding. Apparently, vee-validate has a shortcut for v-model-support.

@MoritzRingler thank you, it works now, i added modelValue : string to props and changed this line const { errors, value, meta } = useField<string | null>(props.name)  by this const { errors, value, meta } = useField(() => props.name, undefined, {   syncVModel: true, });  

That's great! Consider turning your comment into an answer, it might help someone else.
